# What is the security issue with the Safe module?

Tags: perl, security

I have seen some talk recently about how the [Safe](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Safe/Safe.pm) module has security flaws (eg it is being removed from PostgreSQL).  What is the flaw?

Comment: I thought Safe was dropped from PostgreSQL because it breaks UTF-8, not from any security issues.

Comment: Do you have a link to the talk?

Comment: @simbabque http://code.activestate.com/lists/perl5-porters/236848/ it doesn't get more clear than: lexer bugs are now security bugs

Comment: @Borodin This [commit](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/commit/1f474d299d) says they are removing Safe because it is "fundamentally insecure".

Comment: @Chas.Owens: Thank you. I hadn't heard of that. It's splendidly ironic.